# Saiku: How to obtain licence for Saiku Pentaho plugin?

Tags: saiku

I am trying the Saiku Plugin for Pentaho CE. 
The plugin was successfully installed. Now It is asking to obtain a license from

https://licensing.meteorite.bi

But the site appears to be down for several days now. Is there another option to obtain a community license?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Saiku EE plugin asks to get a license on licensing.meteorite.bi but it returns service unavailable. Download URLs I found with Google go to 404 error. If they wanted to drop the Community Edition, they should redirect it to a page announcing the changes and keep poviding its latest version, not make it all offline with error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Seems Like the licencing page has moved to

https://license.meteorite.bi/

Comment: This is Enterprise Edition. We are looking for Community Edition.

Comment: @LucianoBrum , please go to the link again the last option is to generate the license for the community edition .

Comment: Yes, you are right. But that 60 days license is something new.

Comment: @LucianoBrum i registered for it , seems like that license is valid for about a year .

Comment: But this license is for Saiku 4 and Pentaho can't use just Saiku 3. Can I have community license to Saiku3 or use Saiku4 with Pentaho8?

Comment: @LászlóTóth . seems like they longer support this , i can point you to this repository https://github.com/zhicwu/docker-biserver-ce/blob/master/ext/pentaho-solutions/system/saiku/license.lic    ... For the purpose of Trying it out i suppose you could use this .

Comment: Thank you, for the repo, but this is a coded licence, and our server parameters are different.